# Does ECS Agent require an Amazon Linux AMI in order to run?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I am launching a pair of subnets with a VPC and a public load balancer in ECS Fargate launch mode.

I am having the issue that for some reason, ECS agent does not populate "AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_RELATIVE_URI" environmental variable and therefore, my nodejs aws-sdk is not able to fetch credentials from the IAM role.

Trying to discard possible causes, I came across the following question:

Is is possible that I need to run an official Amazon Linux AMI in order to get ECS Agent to work? (my current app does run alpine linux in the container)

Comment: With fargate you don't have to run any agent on your instances.

Comment: @Marcin the ECS agent I understand is automatic in Fargate mode. But since it is suposed to populate "AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_RELATIVE_URI" I was assuming something with the Agent failed. [Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-iam-roles.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If "AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_RELATIVE_URI" is not populated, check that you have assigned a Task role in the task definition:

### Taskdef:

```
{
    "family": "",
    "taskRoleArn": "",             <============== Task role
```

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-iam-roles.html#specify-task-iam-roles

Comment: This was exactly what I was missing. I had assign a taskExecutionRole but not a taskRole.. Thanks!